# Azure Web App FTP permission is denied and cannot upload files and cannot create folders

Tags: azure, permissions

I'm managing small web app, deploying with (always) FTP. My teammate requested me to upload a folder including small teaser website. As usual routine, I opened the Azure Web App Deployment Center FTP dashboard and copied server address and credentials and pasted them into FileZilla(latest version). Login went well and I could see file list and folders. However, when I tried to upload files, remove existing files, all of the writing attempts failed with 550 Access is denied error. What could be the cause of this?

On the other hands, I could remove existing files on KUDU debug console.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I check the ftp link the deployment center provide, looks like the portal provides a read-only ftp link. So go to your web app, click **Get publish profile**, choose the publishUrl under tag `profileName=<yourwebname-FTP>`.

Comment: you were right! the dashboard provided the FTP url tagged by "Readonly - FTP" in publish profile. logging into "FTP" url instead of "Readonly - FTP" solved the problem. Thank you so much!